# Foursquare API Venues returning almost empty venues intent=browse

Tags: foursquare

I've been looking at the Foursquare API, I'm trying to do requests for venues with a url like "https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?limit=50&intent=browse&m=foursquare&ne=20.6077948349134,-105.235476512856&v=20150610&sw=20.6055471650866,-105.237877821883&oauth_token=${token}" At some point this kind of requests were returning a fair amount of venues but recently the API started to return almost empty venues array in the response. Any Ideas? Has something changed recently?

Cheers
Ignacio

Answer (score 0):

The solution that worked for me was changing: `intent=browse` to `intent=checkin` or removing this part completely to fall back to the default. Right after this change I'm seeing full list of venues.

Comment: Thanks, Wotjek, I've tried your suggestion at the Foursquare API explorer but it did not return me any venues, instead it returned me an error. The url I'm trying it is returning me just 1 or 2 venues but not the right number, while I was trying before it was returning much more than 1 or 2 :\. This is the url of the API explorer. [link](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/explore#req=venues/search%3Flimit%3D50%26intent%3Dbrowse%26m%3Dfoursquare%26ne%3D20.6077948349134,-105.233075345487%26v%3D20150610%26sw%3D20.6055471650866,-105.235476654513)

Answer (score 0):

add &intent=browse to URL but it works only with  **ll** and **radius** parameters, or the **sw** and **ne**.

BTW on sept15 was an issue with foursquare API

Comment: Please check this [URL](http://stackoverflow.com/help) it will be useful to raise your content quality up