# Foursquare Venues Search Results Significantly Different

Tags: foursquare

I am observing the same issues here: 
[Foursquare API doesn't work when searching main categories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32697589/foursquare-api-doesnt-work-when-searching-main-categories)

and my question relates to this:
[Foursquare API Venues returning almost empty venues intent=browse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32683143/foursquare-api-venues-returning-almost-empty-venues-intent-browse)

But the answer provided (remove the Category ID) has not changed the results. I sent a Tweet to the Foursquare API Twitter account but have not heard a response. The results of my query changed September 18th and have not returned back to normal as of now.

So far I have tried:

1. Remove category id (no change).
2. Changed version date from a dynamically generated value using PHP
       `$version = date('Ymd');` to a static string value `v=20150918` (no change).
3. Added `query=restaurant` which did return results but only items with the query term. For my application this is an incomplete set and unacceptable.
4. Removed the `query=restaurant` and `categoryId=4d4b7105d754a06374d81259`. This returned all results as expected so for my application which is only concerned with Food this is unacceptable.
5. Scrapped the the entire venues search API call and used the venues explore API. This reutrned results similar to the ones I was receiving before September 18th.

My question:

Does anyone from Foursquare have an explanation about why this is happening and a recommendation on how to resolve? If not, does anyone here on StackOverflow see another option aside from resorting to item 5 of scrapping the venues search API and going with the venues explore API?

I am reluctant to go the way of #5 because:

1. The venues search API has seemingly stopped working for no apparent or obvious reason. Will it begin working again and I just need to be patient despite that now my site is giving mixed results at best and no results at worst?
2. I would need to rewrite the script that inserts data into my database and also the script that displays the data on the map.

This is also my first question here. If there are best practices I am not adhering to I would appreciate a heads up.

Thank you.